# JS framework/library with dynamic reults (AJAX calls) from Database using PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, asynchronous, frameworks

I am looking for Javascript framework which can easly use asynchronous calls. It mean, I have i.e. products in Database. On the website is filter to show results which user wish to see. I don't want to get whole Product table from Database to json data. 
I would like to use javascript function which make AJAX request for php file which return filtered data. Next I could update table with result.

I know, I can use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "php/script1.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&...", // var's are filters
    success: function(data){
        // do data update in result table for user
    }
});
```

But I have problems with using it. My code is horrible, it is disordered etc.

With framework, the best MVC it would be easier to have better code.
And writing whole website using method above is difficult for me (code is not clear).

I was excited to use Angular but it is only client side. Generaly I would like to use Symfony3 for build main website structure, I need to use JS only for "extend" HTML possibilities like Angular did it.

Comment: What are you actually looking for here ?? Kinda confusing question?

Comment: With AJAX you normally can do what you want to do

Comment: @Eddsters Please, be more professional and use arguments in discussion. Read article I found and than think about confusing. If you think my question is not clear then please, write me this I will correct my question.

Comment: @Jean-maxime No. I am using AJAX too. But it is not I want to do. Because pure AJAX is not clear, code is awful etc. Look at the article it shows what huge is the difference when you use library nativly written for asynchronous JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found propper answer:  **Async.js, Step.js, Node Fibers, Syncify.js**, etc.

It is from big, well-written article:

https://www.airpair.com/javascript/async-javascript-libraries

It gives me full satisfaction. Maybe I asked about this using wrong words. Then please, write me a comment I will correct this. Sorry, I am not proffesional.

Comment: Sorry Arrowman wasnt trying to be unprofessional, but the jQuery AJAX function is good enough to do everything, why dont you want to use that?

The thing is you dont want to include a whole frame work JUST for the ajax functionality.

Comment: @Eddsters But this topic is about **framewok**. Not jQuery AJAX. I wrote that I am using method which you proposed. And code with this methid is awful. Frameworks do code a lot of more organized and generaly nice. Isn't this make a difference? For me like Hell and Heaven.